# Running localhost webapp projects under domain name using fiddler2

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, tomcat, localhost

I have a Tomcat server running on my local dev machine(running Windows8) & I use fiddler2 to assign an alias to `localhost` as my domain name (www.mydomainName.com), so my application webpages open in the browser like this:

```
 http://www.mydomainName.com/myAppName/welcome.html
```

instead of

```
 http://localhost:8080/myAppName/welcome.html
```

But I want to my webapp pages urls to omit 'myAppName' & be something like :

```
http://www.mydomainName.com/welcome.html
```

How could I configure to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a virtual host. Add a <Host> element under the <Engine> element in your server.xml.

e.g. <Host name="{domain_name.com}" appBase="{path_to_your_webapp}" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>

For more information, see http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatDevelopmentVirtualHosts
Also, instead of using fiddler2, you can use your hosts file to assign 127.0.0.1 to mydomainname.com